# Dynamic ASP.NET MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm confused about MVC routes. Let's say I have this domain: poopoopants.com. I want some standard URLs off the root that go to an "About" page or "Contact" page:

```
http://poopoopants.com/about
http://poopoopants.com/contact
```

Now, I'm also going to have an infinite amount of these two routes below, where "[user]" is a variable for the username for a person registered with an account on poopoopants.com, and [file-path] is a URL-sanitize file path **that may contain the / character**:

```
http://poopoopants.com/[user]
http://poopoopants.com/[user]/[file-path]
```

So I'm assuming I'd have one `IndexController` with an `Index` action for `/`, `About` action for `/about`, `Contact` action for `/contact`, and one `UserController` with `Index` action for `/[user]/` and `File` action for `/[user]/[file-path]`.

My question concerns definite the routes in `Global.asax.cs`. So far I've got:

```
routes.MapRoute("Index", "/", new { controller = "Index", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("About", "/about", new { controller = "Index", action = "About" });
routes.MapRoute("Contact", "/contact", new { controller = "Index", action = "Contact" });
```

But what do I specify for the /[user] and /[user]/[file-path] routes, and what are the corresponding method signatures of their actions in `UserController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test them, but it should work:

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "User",
    "{username}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index" }   
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "File",
    "{username}/{filepath}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "File" }
```

Method signatures:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username);
public ActionResult File(string username, string filepath);
```

Also, you can make your Index controller Route probably in one MapRoute clause.

Usefull tool: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: I had to change the URL parameter for the "File" route to "{username}/{*filepath}" to support filepaths with '/' in them, but that worked perfectly--thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how I could have one route for Contact and About though, because the User route will capture anything not explicitly defined already as a route, right?

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. Quick testing proved that ;) Glad I could help, good luck with your project.